# Script to filter nginx logs to automatically running nftables

Tags: nginx, scripting, nftables

I have a domain served by nginx. nginx logs have this format:

```
178.128.120.151 - - [19/Jul/2023:20:27:25 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
178.128.120.151 - - [19/Jul/2023:20:27:25 +0200] "GET /1.php HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
95.214.27.160 - - [19/Jul/2023:20:28:24 +0200] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "http://84.120.157.219:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
```

I want to *make an script* (bash, python, whatever) to see the IPs which access to my server and filter this way:

- if the requested path is `/`, `/robots.txt` or `/favicon.ico`, then nothing happens
- but if the requested path is something else, the call `nft add element inet my_table badips { <IP> }`

Preferred to analyze in live the nginx logs, to detect the traffic meanwhile it happens.

Comment: `fail2ban` can help you

Comment: @AlexD fail2ban is good program but it is not what I want because it sees unauthorized access to ssh, nginx, etc. It's a canion to kill flyes